# Display y axis value with B(billion) or M(million) in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have some values on Y-axis(look at picture)! I want to them be like **100M**, **200M**,...

I'm using MPAndroidchart. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: I think MPAndroidchart currently does not have this feature. You can only achieve it through customized y-axis entries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with an [AxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface) . You can write your own pretty easily if you need to, but MPAndroidChart already comes with a [LargeValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/LargeValueFormatter.java) that does what you are describing.

From the AxisValueFormatter [help page](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface#predefined-formatters) section on predefined formatters:

> LargeValueFormatter: Can be used for formatting large values >
>   "1,000". It will turn values like "1,000" into "1k", "1,000,000" will
>   be "1m" (million), "1,000,000,000" will be "1b" (billion) and values
>   like one trillion will be e.g. "1t".

Example use:

```
YAxis left = chart.getAxisLeft();
left.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
```